# Redhat Linux operating system patching silently triggers software package upgrade?

Tags: linux, upgrade, yum, rhel7, patch

When patching the operating system, some software packages can also be upgraded. The incidents in our experience include silently upgrading Python, Logstash, etc. The OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo); not sure if YUM triggered the upgrades.

The unintentional upgrades often lead to compatibility issues and have caused major service interruptions to us. I have encountered this situation for several times.

I am wondering what is the root cause, how to reproduce it for testing, and how to prevent it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Looks like you have set up some automatic update ?

Comment: The system does not have package yum-cron installed. It may be something similar but not exactly "Automatic Update". I have already applied the workaround of "exclude=..." in yum.conf, and the issue did not happen again afterward. It is still better to know the root cause because the issue not occurring might be just not reproduced yet. Thank you for the prompt help, @KnudLarsen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ask Redhat how to stop automatic updates.

---

How to prevent updating of [package-name] :

Add one or more lines to /etc/yum.conf , example

```
exclude=kernel*
```

The wildcard ( * ) is important.

Comment: As said, the issue did not happen again after applying this workaround. However, I am not confident in whether the issue is prevented or just not reproduced yet without knowing the exact root cause. Thanks in advance for further help.